# instantiating an object with a dictionary field prints empty

Tags: python, dictionary

In the following code, I'm trying to print a dictionary that contains the node gateway id as well as the node id as {1:gatewayid, 2:deviceNodeId}, however when instantiating the gateways and the nodes with the dictionary field, it prints an empty dictionary. I'll greatly appreciate your help please:

```
class Node():
    def __init__(self,id, gatewayIds):
        self.id=id
        self.gatewayIds={}
class LevelNNode(Node):
    def __init__(self, id, gatewayIds):
        super(LevelNNode,self).__init__(id, gatewayIds)
        self.balance=0
totalLevels=2
Dn = 10 
Gn = 2  
NODES = []
GATEWAYIDS = [chr(x+97) for x in range(Gn)]
if totalLevels==2:
    for i in GATEWAYIDS: # Create all the gateways
        otherGatewayIds = GATEWAYIDS.copy()
        otherGatewayIds.remove(i)
        NODES.append(LevelNNode(i, {1:i}))
    deviceNodeId = 1  # Create the nodes for the level below
    for i in GATEWAYIDS:
        for j in range(Dn):
            NODES.append(Node(deviceNodeId, {1:i, 2:deviceNodeId}))
            deviceNodeId += 1

for x in NODES:
    print (x.id, x.gatewayIds)
```

Answer (score 0):

That's because you set the instance variable equal to `{}` and don't actually use the parameter you pass in. In the `Node`'s `__init__` try this: `self.gatewayIds=gatewayIds`